# Guard + Zeus + Rspec-Rails: undefined method 'configure' for Rspec:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, zeus

I'm using the following:

```
Rails 4.1.1
guard-zeus 2.0.0
rspec-rails 3.0.1
```

Out of box default `rails g rspec:install` and `guard init`

When I run `guard` and save a spec file, I get the error:

```
undefined method `configure` for RSpec:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I can run specs with `rspec spec` and `rake` just fine.

In `spec_helper`, if I `require 'rspec/rails` before the configure block,
guard works fine, but then `rspec spec` fails with the error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Autoload (NameError)
```

I'm guessing there's a problem with load order now that `rails_helper` and `spec_helper`
are separated.

Two questions:

1. How can I fix this?
2. Is there a different solution for continuous integration *locally* that you can recommend that works with latest Rails and Rspec.

You only have to answer one question.

Comment: Could you show your spec_helper file and what line you are getting that error?

Answer (score 5):

The following fix worked for me:

```
#spec/spec_helper.rb
require 'rspec/core'
```

Comment: he doesn't need to

Comment: Works for me. How did you know you had to run that?

Answer (score 3):

Throwing out a quick answer that may be the problem.  Your spec_helper file should have the following order:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
```

rspec/rails needs to be required after the config/environment require.

Comment: Thank you for your info, I have the problem and I added your solution

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
undefined method `configure` for RSpec:Module (NoMethodError)
```

suggests you are are missing a

```
require 'rspec'
```

This normally isn't necessary, but if you put it in your `spec/spec_helper.rb` that should work.

(If you run RSpec directly, it's included already with RSpec).

The reason it's not included is perhaps:

- you are not running guard through bundler
- or your Gemfile does not have:

  ```
  gem 'rspec' # without the require: false
  ```
- or something may be wrong with your `.rspec` file (which should be present)

The `require 'rspec/rails'` should probably go into the `spec/rails_helper.rb`...

... but a better way would be to update your rspec-rails gem and run:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

and if you're prompted - used 'd' to differences (and ideally use the recommended changes).

Answer (score 1):

You should add following require to top of file `spec_helper.rb`

```
require 'rspec/rails'
```

Take the reference here: [Zeus GitHub issue 308](https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/308)