# RSpec 3.1 with Zeus, should I require 'rspec/rails' in spec_helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, zeus

With `rspec-rails` 3.0+ the test setup is split into `spec_helper` and `rails_helper` and I noticed that the generated `spec_helper` does not `require 'rspec/rails'`.

This causes zeus to crash:

```
spec_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for RSpec:Module (NoMethodError)
```

The most common response to [this issue](https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/474) is to `require 'rspec/rails'`.

**But won´t this defeat the whole purpose of splitting rails specs and  PORO specs which just use the `spec_helper`? Or does this not matter since Zeus preloads Rails anyways?**

**Should I do something like this in my `spec_helper`?**

```
# Zeus does not preload RSpec
require 'rspec/core' unless defined? RSpec.configure
```

**Note** that in the generated `rails_helper` contains:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
```

Comment: related but not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939918/guard-zeus-rspec-rails-undefined-method-configure-for-rspecmodule

Comment: Also see https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/474

Comment: I had this same issue. But I got it fixed without adding anything in spec_helper.rb, Do you have guard setup?

Comment: Yes, but I always make sure the suite runs without Guard.

Comment: okay. found it, `gem 'guard-rspec'` add this to gemfile, This might be little strange, But I was able to reproduce it and then it got fixed after adding this. There is a somekind of dependency. which is trying to access Rspec before its loaded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing is essentially a bug in Zeus. (It is fixed in a commit -- see comment below for link)

You're correct that you should do this for now:

```
# Zeus does not preload RSpec
require 'rspec/core' unless defined? RSpec.configure
```

Q. But won´t this defeat the whole purpose of splitting rails specs and PORO specs which just use the spec_helper?

A. Not really, because the purpose of that split is/was to let RSpec be used in multiple contexts; your context is Rails, so you do need the `rspec/rails`.

When you require `rspec/core` that should be enough to let Zeus do its startup (which should in turn require `rspec/rails`). If you discover that Zeus still isn't working, then do the recommended require `rspec/rails` until the Zeus team sorts out their setup.

Q. You asked: Or does this not matter since Zeus preloads Rails anyways?

A. Correct, it doesn't matter for your case. The issue is really just a load ordering glitch in the Zeus generated files for a brand new project.

Comment: The issue is now fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/burke/zeus/commit/d126abfe42e05188e8ce85bbd87a4d7f02d1d9de) Zeus now checks if there is a rails_helper and load that instead.

Answer (score 4):

the quickest and probably least invasive fix is to move

```
require 'rpsec/rails'
```

above

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

in the rails_helper.rb file

so that it looks like the following:

```
require 'rpsec/rails'
require 'spec_helper'
```